# Is there a workaround for different MD5sum versions between nodes?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. I have done a school project modifying and applying [rovio](https://github.com/ethz-asl/rovio) to run with our data a few years ago. Now I have left school and I am trying to reproduce the same experiment on my local machine.

However, when I play our rosbag, i got this error

```
Client [/rovio] wants topic /novatel/oem7/bestpos to have datatype/md5sum 
[novatel_oem7_msgs/BESTPOS/cbda32531630d034a4a2332c885a856e], but our version has 
[novatel_oem7_msgs/BESTPOS/6d32934a60a2791025b60e069cbfca8d]. Dropping connection.
```

I did some research on similar issues. Apparently the md5sum version of /novatel/oem7/bestpos in my rosbag (outdated version) does not match the version I compiled rovio with.

Is there a way to make the two versions match? I have left school so I don't have access to equipment to record a new rosbag to play with.

Setup: Ubuntu 20.04, ROS Noetic

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/414331/is-there-a-workaround-for-different-md5sum-versions-between-nodes?/) by [zenuri5482](https://answers.ros.org/users/145315/zenuri5482/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2023-04-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found out that older versions can be easily accessed through github commits. So I just simply installed an older version and solved the problem.

---

Originally posted by [zenuri5482](https://answers.ros.org/users/145315/zenuri5482/) with karma: 16 on 2023-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0